# What's the keyboard shortcut of next option in completion list of Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: keyboard, jupyter-notebook, shortcut

For example, input the following codes in the first cell of a Jupyter Notebook in a browser:

`aaa = 1
aab = 2`

In the second cell, after inputing `aa<TAB>`, a completion list containing `aaa` and `aab` appears.
I want to select `aab` with keyboard. But after tried TAB, Up/Down key and Ctrl-p, no one works. I have to use the mouse to select `aab`.
And I've not found documents on Internet about this shortcut.

Question: how to choose `aab` with keyboard shortcuts?

Thanks.